# SQL Server query need to pull data from group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have below data and from highlighted groups I want to pull min datetime (Grayed out rows)from each group, but the data in the all columns are same except date. I used Min aggregate but I am missing date 2019-09-28-12.31.47.653829 row. Not sure how to get all 3 rows from the group. Please help me out Thanks

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result in text format not image.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this as a gaps and island problem. You want the minimum date of adjacent rows that have the same value in all columns expect date, and then pull out the record that has the minimum date.

Here is one way to solve it using `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select 
    id, 
    division, 
    sub_div, 
    status, 
    queue,
    min(event_dattim) min_event_dattim
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by event_dattim) rn1,
        row_number() over(
            partition by id, division, sub_div, status, queue
            order by event_dattim
        ) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by 
    id, 
    division, 
    sub_div, 
    status, 
    queue, 
    rn1 - rn2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your Answer! I tried suggested SQL query but, still missing date 2019-09-28-12.31.47.653829 row for reviewed status.